# how to disable copy in ext.net textfield?

Tags: html, asp.net

```
 <ext:TextField runat="server" ID="txtTruck" FieldStyle="text-transform: uppercase;" regex="^[A-Za-z0-9-.]+$" MarginSpec="4 5 5 9" LabelAlign="left" Disabled="true">
          <Listeners>
              <AfterRender Handler="this.el.dom.setAttribute('onPaste', 'return false');" />
          </Listeners>

 </ext:TextField>
```

i only able to disable the paste function but i also want to **disable the copy function**. I tried add **oncopy="return false"** but there is **no function** and it is for **asp.net.**

Answer (score 0):

code:

```
 field.on({
        paste: function (field, e, eOpts) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
```